# My Sprite class generates a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error, and is sometimes NULL? Rect has weird values?

Tags: sdl2, c++

So, lets start off with the weird `Sprite*` object sometimes being `NULL`.

I run my game, the `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error comes and sometimes, only sometimes my `Sprite*` has a value when it crashes.

Sometimes it has a memory address and other times it is just `NULL`.

Though, even when it has a memory address the game generates the same error.

Here's how I define my Sprite class :

```
std::map<std::string, Sprite*> sprites;
```

I use this function to create a new sprite :

```
void Graphics::CreateSprite(std::string ID, std::string textureID, int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
    std::cout << imagePaths["Square"] << std::endl;
    sprites.insert(std::make_pair(ID, new Sprite(imagePaths[textureID], x, y, width, height, windowRenderer)));
}
```

And I call it like this :

```
graphicsManager->CreateSprite("Test", "Square", 32, 32, 100, 50);
```

And if I `std::cout` the sprite using this `GetSprite` function ( to get the memory address, so I can check if it's NULL) :

```
Sprite* Graphics::GetSprite(std::string spriteID)
{
    std::map<std::string,Sprite*>::iterator it;
    it = sprites.find("Square");
    return it->second;
}
```

Calling it like this :

```
std::cout << graphicsManager->GetSprite("Test") << std::end;
```

I get the output of a memory address so the Sprite is not `NULL`.

---

Now, to the weird values in my `SDL_Rect`.

The SDL_Rec is defined like this :

```
SDL_Rect m_rect;
```

Initialised like this : (in the constructor of the Sprite class)

```
m_rect.x = x;
m_rect.y = y;

if (width == 0)
{
    m_rect.w = textureSurface->w;
}
else {
    m_rect.w = width;
}

if (height == 0)
{
    m_rect.h = textureSurface->h;
}
else {
    m_rect.h = height;
}
```

The parameters being :

```
Sprite::Sprite(std::string imgPath, int x, int y, int width, int height, SDL_Renderer* windowRenderer)
```

Which is called when you create the sprite using the function I posted above.

The values in this case should be :

> x axis : 32
>
> y axis : 32
>
> width : 100
>
> height : 50

However, when I check the values they are :

> x axis : -1869611001
>
> y axis : -1869574000
>
> width : -443987883
>
> height : 1889462621

They are like this before the game crashes as well.

---

And now onto the actual crash of my game :

The error looks like this :

> Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1 address=0x7)

And the error is created on this line when I try to give my `m_rect` (`SDL_Rect`) a value :

```
void Sprite::Move(int offsetX, int offsetY)
{
    m_rect.x += offsetX;  <--- error here!
    m_rect.y += offsetY;
}
```

And the Move function is called like this :

```
graphicsManager->GetSprite("Test")->Move(1, 1);
```

Right after I create the Sprite using the CreateSprite function.

---

**Edit 1**

I played around with the diagnostics tools on the scheme thing, checked malloc, NSZombies objects and such, however none of them worked so I disabled all of them and tried again.

Suddenly my application didn't crash???

However when I tried running it right after, it once again crashed?

I'm so confused...

---

**Edit 2**

So, the next day everything started working again with no modifications to the code.

Now I'm even more confused. lol

Comment: Did you use a step-by-step debugger to validated all the calls and all the objects are valid? `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` looks like you're using a non valid object.

Comment: What does your texture/sprite map look like in the debugger? You might be using wrong key values somewhere.

Comment: @AlexandreVaillancourt Somehow, everything started working the next day, without any modifications to the code.

Comment: In addition to my answer, I suggest you change the signature of the method `Sprite* Graphics::GetSprite(std::string spriteID)` to `Sprite* Graphics::GetSprite(const std::string& spriteID)` to avoid a useless string copy :)

Answer (score 4):

There is a code smell here:

```
Sprite* Graphics::GetSprite(std::string spriteID)
{
    std::map<std::string,Sprite*>::iterator it;
    it = sprites.find("Square");
    return it->second;
}
```

By not making sure that the object is valid, the `it` could be `sprites.end()`. According to [some documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/end/), it's very dangerous to dereference the `end()` iterator. You **can't** be sure that the `->second` part will be `nullptr` (in fact, you can be sure that it will **not** be `nullptr`; it will be garbage, that's c++).

Also, you're not using the parameter you pass to the function:

To fix this, modify your code:

```
Sprite* Graphics::GetSprite(std::string spriteID)
{
    std::map<std::string,Sprite*>::iterator it;
    it = sprites.find(spriteID);
    if( it != sprites.end() )
      return it->second;

    return nullptr;
}
```

Comment: My application randomly started working again today with no modifications to the code... However I will add this to the code.